# how to check if textbox is not empty in formview

Tags: asp.net, events, textbox, formview

i have a page where i can create users that can then log into the page. on the page where i create the users, there is a formview. in this formview there are multiple textboxes and dropdownlists. how can i check if the textboxes are empty? i tried to do it code-behind but i cant access the textboxes from there...

here is my code:

```
<asp:FormView ID="fvBenutzer" runat="server" DefaultMode="Insert" DataKeyNames="BenutzerID" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1">
            <InsertItemTemplate>
                Gruppe:
                <asp:TextBox ID="tbGruppe" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("GruppenID") %>' /><br />
                Titel:
                <asp:TextBox ID="tbTitel" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Titel") %>' /><br />
                Bezeichnung:
                <asp:DropDownList AppendDataBoundItems="true" runat="server" ID="ddwnBezeichnung" Text='<%# Bind("Bezeichnung")%>'>
                    <asp:ListItem Text="Mitarbeiter" Value="Mitarbeiter"></asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Text="Praktikant" Value="Praktikant"></asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Text="Azubi" Value="Azubi"></asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Text="Umschüler" Value="Umschüler"></asp:ListItem>
                </asp:DropDownList><br />
                Vorname:
                <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="tbVorname" Text='<%# Bind("Vorname")%>' /><br />
                Nachname:
                <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="tbNachname" Text='<%# Bind("Nachname")%>' /><br />
                Geburtsdatum:
                <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="tbGeburtsdatum" Text='<%# Bind("Geburtsdatum")%>' /><br />
                Geburtsort:
                <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="tbGeburtsort" Text='<%# Bind("Geburtsort")%>' /><br />
                Nationalität:
                <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="tbNationalitaet" Text='<%# Bind("Nationalität")%>' /><br />
                Straße:
                <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="tbStraße" Text='<%# Bind("Straße")%>' /><br />
                Hausnummer:
                <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="tbHausnummer" Text='<%# Bind("Hausnummer")%>' /><br />
                PLZ:
                <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="tbPLZ" Text='<%# Bind("PLZ")%>' /><br />
                Ort:
                <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="tbOrt" Text='<%# Bind("Ort")%>' /><br />
                Land:
                <asp:DropDownList AppendDataBoundItems="true" runat="server" ID="ddwnLand" Text='<%# Bind("Land")%>'>

                </asp:DropDownList><br />
                Mobil:
                <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="tbMobil" Text='<%# Bind("Mobil")%>' /><br />
                Fax:
                <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="tbFax" Text='<%# Bind("Fax")%>' /><br />
                Festnetz:
                <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="tbFestnetz" Text='<%# Bind("Festnetz")%>' /><br />
                Email:
                <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="tbEmail" Text='<%# Bind("Email")%>' /><br />
                Homepage:
                <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="tbBenutzerart" Text='<%# Bind("Homepage")%>' /><br />
                Benutzerart:
                <asp:DropDownList AppendDataBoundItems="true" runat="server" ID="ddwnBenutzerart" Text='<%# Bind("Benutzerart")%>'>
                    <asp:ListItem Text="Mitarbeiter" Value="Mitarbeiter"></asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Text="Geschäftsführung" Value="Geschäftsführung"></asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Text="Führungskraft" Value="Führungskraft"></asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Text="Administrator" Value="Administrator"></asp:ListItem>
                </asp:DropDownList><br />
                Urlaubstage:
                <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="tbUrlaubstageInsgesamt" Text='<%# Bind("UrlaubstageInsgesamt")%>' /><br />
                Benutzername:
                <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="tbBenutzername" Text='<%# Bind("Username")%>' /><br />
                Passwort:
                <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="tbPasswort" Text='<%# Bind("UserPassword")%>' /><br />
                <br />
                <asp:Button ID="btnSpeichern" runat="server" CommandName="Insert" Text="Speichern" />
                <asp:Button ID="btnAbbrechen" Text="Abbrechen" runat="server" OnClick="btnAbbrechen_Click" />
            </InsertItemTemplate>
        </asp:FormView>
        <asp:SqlDataSource OnInserting="SqlDataSource1_Inserting" OnInserted="SqlDataSource1_Inserted" ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString %>"
            InsertCommand="INSERT INTO Benutzer (GruppenID, Titel, Bezeichnung, Vorname, Nachname, Geburtsdatum, Geburtsort, Nationalität, Straße, Hausnummer, PLZ, Ort, Land, Mobil, Fax, Festnetz, 
                           Email, Homepage, Benutzerart, UrlaubstageInsgesamt , UrlaubstageRest, Username, UserPassword)
                           VALUES (@GruppenID, @Titel, @Bezeichnung, @Vorname, @Nachname, @Geburtsdatum, @Geburtsort, @Nationalität, @Straße, @Hausnummer, @PLZ, @Ort, @Land, @Mobil, @Fax, @Festnetz, 
                           @Email, @Homepage, @Benutzerart, @UrlaubstageInsgesamt , @UrlaubstageInsgesamt, @Username, @UserPassword)"></asp:SqlDataSource>
```

```
protected void SqlDataSource1_Inserting(object sender, SqlDataSourceCommandEventArgs e)
        {
            //Code to check textboxes goes here...
        }
```

Comment: Do you want to validate textbox and warn user if it is empty? You can use validation controls in formview for this, And you can check sqldatasource parameter value for the textbox in the Inserting event, to check if the textbox is empty try Formview ItemInserting event

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried:

```
TextBox tb = (TextBox)fvBenutzer.FindControl("yourtextboxid");
string text = tb.Text;
```

Edit:
You can stop the insert in the FormView ItemInserting event. For example:

```
protected void fvBenutzer_ItemInserting(object sender, FormViewInsertEventArgs e) 
{
    if(YourValidationCheck() == false)
        e.Cancel = true;
}
```

Don't forget to add `oniteminserting="fvBenutzer_ItemInserting"` to the FormView tag.

Comment: one more thing, how could i abort the insert operation when there is nothing in the textbox? it should just display an error and the values should still be in the textboxes...

Comment: I've added to my answer above

Comment: ok it works again, but the values are gone after the insert command is canceled.